# MVC Model Navigation Property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have two data models, `Address` and `Street`.  `Address` contains properties like the address number, direction (North, South, East, West), and a navigation property (foreign key link) to a `Street`.  The `Street` model contains the actual street name.

I am trying to concatenate the address number, direction, and street name all as one for purposes of display in my views and select lists.  But, the page throws a NullReferenceException if I try to display `FullAddress` in the page view.  I am assuming this is due to trying to access `Street.StreetName` directly from my `Address` class.

It would be fine to concatenate everything in the view, but I want to avoid that since I need to also use the full address within SelectLists/drop down menus.  What's a good way to accomplish this?

Here is the `Address` model:

```
public class Address
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Owner")]
    public int OwnerID { get; set; }
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address Number")]
    public string AddressNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address Direction")]
    public string AddressDirection { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address Street")]
    public int StreetID { get; set; }
    public Street Street { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    public string FullAddress { get { return String.Format("{0} {1}" + (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AddressDirection) ? "" : " " + "{2}"), AddressNumber, AddressDirection, Street.StreetName); } }

    [Display(Name = "Parcel")]
    public string Parcel { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cases")]
    public ICollection<Case> Cases { get; set; }
}
```

`Street` model:

```
public class Street
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "StreetName")]
    public string StreetName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Addresses")]
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller:

```
    // GET: Cases
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        // Take in the page sort parameters
        ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder;
        ViewData["CaseSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "case" : "";
        ViewData["AddressSortParm"] = sortOrder == "address" ? "address_desc" : "address";
        ViewData["StatusSortParm"] = sortOrder == "status" ? "status_desc" : "status";
        ViewData["Page"] = page;

        // Show page 1 if there isn't a search being done
        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;

        // Address search
        var nEATContext = _context.Cases
        .Include(a => a.Address)
        .ThenInclude(s => s.Street)
        .Include(d => d.Department)
        .Include(i => i.Inspector)
        .Include(s => s.Status)
        .Include(ci => ci.CaseIssues)
        .ThenInclude(i => i.Issue)
        .Where(c => c.Address.FullAddress.Contains(String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) ? "" : searchString));  // allow to search by address

        ViewResult view;
        int pageSize = 8;   // set page size

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            // Sort by case number, ascending
            case "case":
                view = View(await nEATContext.OrderBy(c => c.ID).ToPagedListAsync(pageSize, page ?? 1));
                break;
            // Sort by case number, descending
            case "case_desc":
                view = View(await nEATContext.OrderByDescending(c => c.ID).ToPagedListAsync(pageSize, page ?? 1));
                break;
            // Sort by address, ascending alphabetically
            case "address":
                view = View(await nEATContext.OrderBy(a => a.Address.FullAddress).ToPagedListAsync(pageSize, page ?? 1));
                break;
            // Sort by address, descending alphabetically
            case "address_desc":
                view = View(await nEATContext.OrderByDescending(a => a.Address.FullAddress).ToPagedListAsync(pageSize, page ?? 1));
                break;
            // Sort by status, ascending alphabetically
            case "status":
                view = View(await nEATContext.OrderBy(c => c.Status).ToPagedListAsync(pageSize, page ?? 1));
                break;
            // Sort by status, descending alphabetically
            case "status_desc":
                view = View(await nEATContext.OrderByDescending(c => c.Status).ToPagedListAsync(pageSize, page ?? 1));
                break;
            // Default sort by case number, ascending
            default:
                view = View(await nEATContext.OrderByDescending(c => c.ID).ToPagedListAsync(pageSize, page ?? 1));
                break;
        }
        return view;
    }
```

The program is complaining as soon as I add the `Street.StreetName` reference.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. NEAT.Models.Address.get_FullAddress() in Address.cs
+
        public string FullAddress { get { return String.Format("{0} {1}" + (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AddressDirection) ? "" : " " + "{2}"), AddressNumber, AddressDirection, Street.StreetName); } }
```

**Address database table**

[image: Address database table]

**Street database table**

[image: Street database table]

Comment: Make sure to Include your Street entity when querying your Address

Comment: How are you retrieving your `Address` from the db?

Comment: My apologies, I edited my original post to include a portion of my controller class.  I am using .Include in the Address and .ThenInclude on Street.

Comment: When do you get the error? When querying or when attempting to read the FullAddress property?

Comment: The error shows up when loading my View.  I suppose it is when I am reading the FullAddress property from the View.

Comment: SO if you include Street but it still is null so it mean some address have not set the Street in your database

Comment: That was my thought too, but all Addresses have StreetIDs...It's strange but I'm thinking the Address can't access the Street.StreetName value from its model.  But, I'm not sure how to include it.

Comment: @CodeNotFound is correct. There is no other possible cause here. As long as you're eagerly loading the relationship (via `Include`), then the only reason it would be null is if there's no street related to that address. Perhaps you're not looking at the right database?

Comment: I've double checked my data and it's all there (accessing localdb with entity framework).  What's interesting is if I remove my Where clause, the data displays perfectly fine.  But, that takes away my ability to filter the results, unless there is another way to do that.  I am passing a searchString to the View to filter the DB results with my controller.

Comment: I think your code should fail at `.Where(c => c.Address.FullAddress.Contains(String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) ? "" : searchString));` because FullAddress can be transtated by EF because it doesn't been mapped to a column on your Database.

Comment: That was the source of my issues!  FullAddress is unknown to EF since it's a computed column in the model.  I've had to adjust my Where clause to concact the individual fields (StreetNumber, StreetAddress, Street.StreetName) and filter off that, instead of just FullAddress.